# Javascript regex for multiliners for new Regexp

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var urlRegExp = new RegExp("/----(-| )BEGIN.[^-]----(-| )END.*(-| )----/","im");
```

I have this regex to match text like below:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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== 
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

but it is not working. Can anybody help?

Comment: How is it not working?

Comment: It is not working... My logic is clear I just want to valid the given string..

Comment: I doubt you are trying to validate a Base64 encoded string using a regex. Do you want to match the text in between `BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` and `-----END CERTIFICATE`? Or this whole example string that is part of a larger context?

Comment: I want to validate whole portion given as input including BEGIN CERTIFICATE  and END CERITIFICATE.

Comment: @SamkitShah: I think you now have at least one working answer. If you are not satisfied, just add comments to the answers.

Comment: Yes,,,,I have one working answer......

Comment: var urlRegExp = /----(-| )BEGIN.*[^-]*----(-| )END.*(-| )----/im; is the final answer

Answer (score 2):

I'd use a regex like this to grab the RSA key:

`/-+BEGIN CERTIFICATE-+([^-]+)-+END CERTIFICATE-+/im`

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the RegExp constructor with a string closed by regex literal delimiterers (`/`). It's so much simpler to use a regex literal directly.

And you have a few errors in your regex like missing a quantifier and not accepting line breaks in the key.

Here's a fixed regular exception:

```
var urlRegExp = /----(?:-| )BEGIN(?:.*?)-+([\w\W]+)----(?:-| )END.*(?:-| )----/i;
console.log(str.match(urlRegExp)[1]) // logs the content
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/risofifobu/1/watch?js,console,output) (click "Run with JS")

Comment: why do you use \w\W  instead of ^-. ^- is used because I don't want to use '-' in the string.

Comment: @SamkitShah I've fixed it and added a link to the demonstration in my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Finally got the perfect answer for given string:
var urlRegExp = /----(-| )BEGIN.*[^-]*----(-| )END.*(-| )----/im;